# Retrieve number of current slide using slideNumber Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reveal.js

I need your help about Reveal.js.

Anyone can explain me how to retrieve the number of my currentslide, and add it into variable ?

I need to add an event on my slide 4.

Thx for the support

Answer (score 2):

You can get the indices  of the current slide with `Reveal.getIndices()`. It returns an object with three properties:

- h: horizontal index of the slide
- v: vertical index of the  slide
- f: Index of a fragment within the slide

Now you can compare the current index with the index of the slide you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', function(evt) {
  if (evt.currentSlide === 4) {
    // Do your stuff
  }
});
```

You can always store `currentSlide` somewhere and then retrieve it later if your action requires it to be done in the middle of the presentation, not on `slidechanged`.

Comment: Yes, is that what i mean, but does it work with a jquery animation?
`code` 
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    

if (event.currentSlide === 4) {

$("canvas").animate({
    
    marginLeft: "4in",
 marginTop:"-1.05in",
    
   
  height:'+=80px',
      width:'+=80px'
});
 }   
});
`code`

Animation is on the middle

Comment: This answer is wrong. `currentSlide` contains the HTML element but not the slide number.

Comment: Yes, @SethosII , there's a slight chance that this answer might have outdated in seven years...

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi See this from version 2.6.2 (last version dating back to before your answer): https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/9da952fea30906090446d038430186b11dba7f13/js/reveal.js#L125-L127. The comment there also says that these are the HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

I do this to get the indice of the SLide:

```
 Reveal.addEventListener('slidechanged', function (evt) {
        ind = Reveal.getIndices().h
        if (ind === 0) {
            ......
        }
        if (ind === 1) {
            .....
        }
 });
```